Evaluate the expresion (k - y) / (b^z - (k + k^a)) where b,z,y and a are real and k = 1, 15
I have to evaluate this expression (k - y) / (b^z - (k + k^a))
This is my attempt to solve the problem
finit
    mov ecx, 15
    mov eax, 1
    
    ; Calcul b^z
    fld b 
    fld z   ;st(0)=z,st(1)=b,st(2)=k/y
    fyl2x; st(0)=b*log*z
    fld1
    fscale; st(0)=2^[b*logz];st(1)=b*log*z
    fld1 
    fld st(1)
    fyl2x ; st(0)=[b*logz],st(1)=2^[b^logz],st(2)=b*logz
    fsubr st(0),st(2);st(0)=blogz-[b^logz]
    f2xm1
    fld1
    fadd
    fstp qword ptr [putere]
    finit
  
loop_k:
    mov [k], eax

    ; Conversie k la float
    fild dword ptr [k]
    fstp qword ptr [k_float]

    ; Calcul (k - y)
    fld qword ptr [k_float]   ; Load k
    fld qword ptr [y]         ; Load y
    fsub                      ; k - y
    fstp qword ptr [numarator]

    ; Calcul k^a
    fld k_float 
    fld a   ;st(0)=z,st(1)=b,st(2)=k/y
    fyl2x; st(0)=b*log*z
    fld1
    fscale; st(0)=2^[b*logz];st(1)=b*log*z
    fld1 
    fld st(1)
    fyl2x ; st(0)=[b*logz],st(1)=2^[b^logz],st(2)=b*logz
    fsubr st(0),st(2);st(0)=blogz-[b^logz]
    f2xm1
    fld1
    fadd
    

    ; Calcul k + k^a
    fld qword ptr [k_float]   ; Load k
    fadd                      ; k + k^a
    fstp qword ptr [sumk]

  
    ; Calcul b^z - (k + k^a)
    fld qword ptr [putere]
    fld qword ptr [sumk]
    fsub                      ; b^z - (k + k^a)

    ; Calcul (k - y) / (b^z - (k + k^a))
    fld qword ptr [numarator]
    fdivr                     ; (k - y) / (b^z - (k + k^a))
    
    fld qword ptr [sum]
    fadd
    fstp qword ptr [sum]


    ; Incrementare k și buclă
    inc eax
    loop loop_k  
  
    ; Afișarea rezultatului
    push dword ptr [sum+4]
    push dword ptr [sum]
    push offset result_msg
    call printf
    add esp, 12

I am not sure that the scaling is correct since I do not know where I can check. If you have a site that does that it would be very helpful.
But the main problem is that whatever values i put, the resultat that is printed is -1.#IND00.
When I do a single loop it prints a value, but not the correct value

Use a debugger to single step the code and verify the partial results.

Please show what is in the result_msg format string for use by printf.
